# android setText with hebrew string in BaseAdapter cause stackoverflow

Tags: android, textview, baseadapter

i've built a BaseAdapter extended class for my list view..

inside i have a TextView field which i want to set by code.
this field represent a facebook status of the user.

this field sometimes gets a text in hebrew, and then it crashes by stackoverflow error.

important to add that this ain't happened when the text the field gets is in english,
and when i've tried to debug it to find the problem, i've used setText with hebrew string inside an activity (not a BaseAdapter) and it worked fine.

this is my class:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;    
import com.WhosAround.R;
import com.WhosAround.AppVariables;    
import com.WhosAround.Facebook.FacebookUser;
import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;    
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;  

public class FriendsFriendsTabList extends BaseAdapter {

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private AppVariables app;
    private final FacebookUser[] chatList;

    public FriendsFriendsTabList(Activity activity) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        app = (AppVariables) activity.getApplicationContext();
        chatList = app.makeApplicationFacebookUsersArray();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return chatList.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.activity_friends_friends_tab_list_row, null);
        if (position % 2 == 0)
            vi.setBackgroundResource(R.color.list_background_light);
        else
            vi.setBackgroundResource(R.color.list_background_dark);

        TextView name = (TextView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.list_friends_friends_tab_name);
        TextView status = (TextView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.list_friends_friends_tab_status);
        ImageView profilePicture = (ImageView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.list_profile_picture);   
        loadStatus(position, status);

        return vi;
    }


    private void loadStatus(final int position, final TextView status) {
        if (chatList[position].getStatus() != null)
            status.setText(chatList[position].getStatus());
        else {
            final Handler handler = new Handler() {
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message message) {                    
                    try {
                        String currentStatus = (String) message.obj;
                        String utf8Status;
                        utf8Status = new String(currentStatus.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
                        chatList[position].setStatus(currentStatus);                    
                        Log.d("status", chatList[position].getStatus()); 
                                                      //this is the line that causes the error
status.setText(utf8Status);

                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            Thread thread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String fqlQuery = "SELECT message FROM status WHERE uid="
                            + Integer.toString(chatList[position].getId())
                            + " LIMIT 1";                    
                     Bundle fqlQueryParams = new Bundle();
                     fqlQueryParams.putString("method", "fql.query");
                     fqlQueryParams.putString("query", fqlQuery);                                       
                    app.getFacebookManager().getFacebookRunner().request(null, fqlQueryParams, new RequestListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object state) {
                            Log.e("Facebook User Status", e.toString());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
                            Log.e("Facebook User Status", e.toString());                            
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, Object state) {
                            Log.e("Facebook User Status", e.toString());                            
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
                            Log.e("Facebook User Status", e.toString());                            
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                            Log.d("Facebook Response", response);
                            JSONArray statusResults = app.convertToJSONArray(response);
                            try {
                                JSONObject statusObject = statusResults.getJSONObject(0);
                                String currentStatus = statusObject.getString("message");                                                               
                                Message message = handler.obtainMessage(1, currentStatus);
                                handler.sendMessage(message);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Log.e("Facebook User Status", e.toString());
                            } 

                        }
                    });

                }
            };
            thread.start();
        }
    }

}
```

i know the code is a bit mass, and that i should use asynctask instead of thread and handlers, but this is only a test, and i wanted to see if it works...

stacktrace:

```
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863): java.lang.StackOverflowError
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at com.ibm.icu4jni.util.LocaleData.get(LocaleData.java:96)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1061)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1031)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2183)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2157)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.text.Styled.drawDirectionalRun(Styled.java:266)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.text.Styled.drawText(Styled.java:362)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.text.Layout.drawText(Layout.java:1546)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.text.Layout.draw(Layout.java:380)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:4417)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6933)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:1648)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3217)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:3030)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1917)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1530)
06-20 19:30:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(3863):     at android.view.ViewRoot.perfor
```

Comment: It helps to provide the stack trace.

Comment: when you're right, you're right... i've added it. thanks !

Comment: @AsafNevo This does not look to be the complete stacktrace. Also please include complete java file with package and import statements

Comment: this is the complete stacktrace, and i've added the import

Comment: Are you sure that hebrew is supported for your version of Android? I recall that not all versions support arabic characters (2.2 adds it I believe).

Comment: yes i'm using 2.3, and again, when trying to run setText("hebrew string") in a regular activity it works..
i think maybe it have something with the memory allocated for the adapter, since hebrew strings take much more memory then english strings

Comment: @AsafNevo : Have you tried logging `utf8Status` to see that it is a valid string? Unless the original string is thousands of characters long, I can't see how this is an issue with hebrew characters as opposed to english ones. The thing that worries me the most is that every time a list item (row) of your `ListView` is drawn, you're calling a method which creates a `Handler` and a `Thread`. Seriously...the call to the adapter's `getView` method should be as efficient as possible and return a view with minimal work.

Comment: @Squonk you're right and this is only a test, i've already written it with an asynctask class. i've logged it and in the log i see the output just fine.. its the weirdest thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your

```
status.setText(utf8Status)
```

is running on the UI Thread? It may not be because of the Threaded Handler. You'll need to try running that as a POST.
However, that usually results in a different error message.

Can you please point out which part of the code it line 96? The one causing the error?

Comment: exactly this: status.setText(utf8Status), i'm sure i'm running it in the UI Thread because when the text is in English there is no problem.. the problem is only with hebrew string...

Comment: this code gets user's facebook status and supposed to show it in the status TextView.. when the status is in english everything is ok. when it's in hebrew i get the stackoverflow above..

Comment: Ahh. I see the comment off to the side now. Humm. Doesn't sound like and UI threading problems. Defiantly languages issues. I wonder if it has anything todo with the local of you app.

Comment: nope... it must be something with the BaseAdapter..
inside my ListView activity, i have an onItemClickListener which show alert box with textview. i have no problem writing hebrew there...