# android list view change TextView afterthe data is populate by adapter

Tags: android, listview

i have a list view with a BaseAdapter for custom view..
i have problem setting hebrew text in my TextView which are in the adapter.
i want to get into each line of the list after the adapter is set..

is there a way that after the list is shown on the screen, i can get into a specific line view, `findById` a TextView and edit it ?
i don't mean the first customize.. i want to change it after it has been loaded...

i can't really understand why it doesn't work in hebrew... but i'm trying to overcome this error..

Comment: love it when people add -1 but not trying to help nor answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can perform your findViewById() call inside of [getView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29)

No. You not able to perform this operation anywhere else and expect to get a handle on the items in your list row besides the BaseAdapter.

Comment: so i'm in a real mass..
can you please be kind to look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123889/android-settext-with-hebrew-string-in-baseadapter-cause-stackoverflow